# React.js Routing to "/" incurs [cannot be invoked without 'new']

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I made a react app with `npx create-react-app`. This is my app.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { render } from "react-dom";
import HomePage from "./components/HomePage";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom"

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/'>{HomePage}</Route>
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
            );
    }
}
```

Everything looks fine to me here, but when I run it with yarn start, I get this error `TypeError: Class constructor HomePage cannot be invoked without 'new'`. It doesn't really make sense because if the route is not '/' then everything works fine. I even have the exact attribute so I don't see how this could be of a problem. My friend has a working sample but it is a function based component rather than a class based one. I'm wondering why my code here doesn't work. Here's his function component:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path = "/" component={HomePage} exact/>

        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whether your `HomePage` component is based on `Class` or `Function`, the right way to use react-router-dom `Route` is

1. use `component` props just like your friend do

or

2. use `render` props and pass your component as a JSX

```
<Route path = "/" render={() => <HomePage/>} exact/>
```